# Math, logic symbol for "instance of"

Tags: logic, notation

I saw a discussion of a possible symbol for "example," but I need "example/instance of." There is of course

$a \in S$

which is **a is a member of/in S**, but is there a specific way of stating

$a "instanceOfSymbol" S$ ?

Comment: "If $a$ satisfies _______ then..."

Comment: What you're asking isn't exactly clear; could you give a concrete example?

Comment: Symbols themselves are just shorthands. There might be such a thing in typed languages, which are becoming more and more common in various theoretical computer science studies, and some foundational studies.

Comment: "I have a collection of names, $N=\{n~:~n~\text{is a name}\}$, e.g. Bill."   Here "e.g. Bill" is interpreted as "Bill" is an example of one of the $n\in N$.  E.g. means *exempli gratia*, loosely translated as *for example*.

Comment: If $S$ is precisely the set of instances of $[\text{thing}]$, then the symbols $\in S$ exactly denote "instances of" $[\text{thing}]$ :) Careful if your $[\text{thing}]$ includes too many instances, you'll run into some paradoxes.

Comment: There's a subtle difference in saying "for example" and "instance of." But I guess, GPerez, you're right, that $a \in S$ is indeed "instance of". However, I was hoping for a more general "instance of" rather than the set theory symbol $\in$.

Comment: @user78162 I only meant that you can design the desired symbol using set theory. I'm sure it isn't necessary to do it this way, but we'd have to ask a logician. In fact it is done, since we can say "a set" e.g. an instance of the thing "set", without appealing to "the set of all sets". However I don't know the precise terms that allow this.

Comment: I believe mathematicians use the words "is a" in place "instaceOfSymbol".  e.g. Suppose $G$ is a Finite Group.  Suppose $f$ is a continuous function.